# What's the difference between 'Go Around' and 'Pull Up'?

Tags: phraseology

We use on the standard RT (radio telephony) *Go Around.* But what's the difference between *Go Around* and *Pull Up*?

Comment: RT = radio telephony (communication between ATCos and Pilots)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Going around is a process, pulling up is an action. When ATC tells you to go around or you say you are going around it means you are initiating a set of actions to abort an approach. Pulling up is a single action, i.e. increasing the angle of attack in order to climb, and would be part of a go-around procedure.

Pull up is a non-standard phrase, in most parts of the world at least, but you might hear it as 'pull up and go around' in Canada. It also might be used in urgent situations to urge a pilot to act to avoid an obstacle or collision.

Comment: You might also hear "pull up" from Bitching Betty.

Comment: This is true @Devil07, but it's not used in RT typically.

Comment: @Devil07 But...not until after you've already ignored her warnings about your sink rate.

Comment: I may be overemphasizing an implicit part of your answer, but isn't "pull up and go around" misleading since the first thing a pilot does during go around is advance the throttle fully and gain speed before gaining altitude?  To me "pull up" sounds like you're try to gain altitude immediately, which in some cases is a fatal mistake.

Comment: I would completely agree @CodyP. Pull up and go around is an official phraseology in Canada, as shown in their RT documentation, unless that's changed in the past few years. Personally I don't like it but it's part of a complete answer.

Comment: @J..., not necessarily. “Sink rate” is only issued during approach, but “pull up” anytime you are getting dangerously close to the ground. So if you are flying level and there is rising ground ahead, you will hear just “terrain, terrain” and then shortly “terrain, pull up”.